# Enable CORS for Spring Cloud Function with Angular

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-cloud-function

I have a Spring Boot application which is using Spring Cloud function to expose the functions as an end points. Currently we are using angular application as a consumer of the functions from the spring boot application. When we call the end point using httpClient module in angular, Its showing CORS error. I have tried different Bean configuration to enable the cors.

### Spring Boot App:

```
@CrossOrigin("*")  -> This did not work
@SpringBootApplication
public class CloudFunctionApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CloudFunctionApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Function<String, String> reverseString() {
        return value -> new StringBuilder(value).reverse().toString();
    }

    @Bean   --> This did not work
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/greeting-javaconfig").allowedOrigins("*");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

### Angular Application.

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpService {

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getReverseStr(): Observable<Response> {
        const body = {"code": 123}
        return this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/reverseString", body); --> Giving cors error
    }
 
}
```

It would be great If some one could help to resolve CORS issue

Comment: typo: `@CorssOrigin("*")  -> This did not work`

Answer (score 0):

Remove `@CrossOrigin("*")` and try using this:

```
public class DevCorsConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
     
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/greeting-javaconfig").allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS");
        }
    }
```

instead of this:

```
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/greeting-javaconfig").allowedOrigins("*");
            }
        };
    }
```

This configuration enables CORS requests from any origin to the `/greeting-javaconfig` endpoint in the application. You can narrow the access by using the `allowedOrigins`, `allowedMethods`, `allowedHeaders`, `exposedHeaders`, `maxAge` or `allowCredentials` methods.

I hope it should help.

Comment: This solutions works only when we use rest controller instead of spring cloud function. Here I am using spring cloud function i.e expose function as an end point.

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation try adding

```
@Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer configurer(){
      return new WebMvcConfigurer(){
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
          registry.addMapping("/*")
              .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:8080");
        }
  };
}
```

This makes the entire application request mappings accessible for all origins

Comment: As I have specified in my above post, this is also not working.

Comment: @M.S.Naidu Yeah But I think you're applying specific mapping. try adding `/*` instead of `/greeting-javaconfig`. This will allow entire application to be mapped

Comment: Even I tried with "/*" but still the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add some HttpOption in your API call ? , something like this :

```
apiURL = environment.urlApi;
 httpOptions = {
   headers: new HttpHeaders({
     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
   })
 }
 constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

 create(body: any): Observable<any> {
   return this.http.post(this.apiURL + "/reverseString", body, this.httpOptions);
 }
```

hope it will help you :)